# Deserializing JSON into nested C# objects

Tags: c#, json, rest

I would like to know if there are any issues passing an object into a RESTful service method, which contains other objects, as well as primitive types

For example, if I have the following code abstraction:

Service Interface

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "projectors", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    void RecordBreakdown(Record record);
```

POCO object

```
public class Record
{     
    [DataMember]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ModelCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ErrorCode Errors { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorCode
{     
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

The class 'Record' contains a reference to the object 'ErrorCode'. Will that cause any problems in the mapping of the JSON attributes to the objects properties. In which case is it better to pass the JSON object in as a string and then use a .net or 3rd party library to deserialise it?

Comment: Are you asking for best practices or did you actually have an error when deserializing?

Comment: In my opinion the best practise is to deserliaze the object with JavascriptSerializer.

Comment: There should not be any problem passing an object that contains another object type within it.

Comment: @DavidL No error. Trying to figure out how to go about it.
Thanks for the other comments